# Can I install my custom APK in Android Box?

Tags: android, touchscreen

Help needed, Can i install my custom apk in the android box?
Actually i am trying to run my application on touch screen TV.
Any Lead will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your TV has the playstore, its highly probable that the APK manager is there. You should be able to install custom made apps after connecting using the USB cable. But this question is very vague. 
You might want to describe;

1. TV model
2. Android version
3. Type of connectors in TV
4. Whether apps can be installed using the playstore.

This might help users when you're asking questions